# std::stringstream and the str method

Tags: c++, stringstream

I noticed something when trying to use the stringstream object. Here is a useless example to explain this:

```
stringstream ss ;
ss << "my string" ;
cout << ss.str() << endl ;
```

Is not equivalent to

```
cout << (stringstream() << "my string").str() << endl ;
```

This leads to a compilation error complaining that ‘class std::basic_ostream’ has no member named ‘str’.

I can't easily explain this. This is not critical for my application but I'm pretty sure this is hiding a c++ trick interesting to be understood.

Note: i'm using gcc with c++14

Comment: Solution: `static_cast< stringstream & >(stringstream() << "my string").str()`. Or, ya know, use the named variable.

Comment: At the end that was obvious, I was just gone the wrong way when searching to explain this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is *not* defined for [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), but for its base class [`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream), hence it does not return a reference to the `std::stringstream` and therefore the method [`str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) (which is a method of `std::stringstream`) is not found.

Technically, the above is actually `std::basic_stringstream<CharT,Traits>` and `std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>`, but you get the idea :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem with this:

```
cout << (stringstream() << "my string").str() << endl;
```

It is that the expression `stringstream() << "my string"` returns a `std::ostream&` object, not a `std::stringstream`.

You can rectify this by defining some appropriate overloads:

```
template<typename Type>
std::stringstream& operator<<(std::stringstream& ss, const Type& type)
{
    static_cast<std::ostream&>(ss) << type;
    return ss;
}

template<typename Type>
std::stringstream& operator<<(std::stringstream&& ss, const Type& type)
{
    static_cast<std::ostream&>(ss) << type;
    return ss;
}

template<typename Type>
std::stringstream& operator>>(std::stringstream& ss, Type& type)
{
    static_cast<std::istream&>(ss) >> type;
    return ss;
}

template<typename Type>
std::stringstream& operator>>(std::stringstream&& ss, Type& type)
{
    static_cast<std::istream&>(ss) >> type;
    return ss;
}
```

Now, when you use the `<<` and `>>` operators on a `std::stringstream` object, it will call these overloads and they will return a `std::stringstream&` so you can use its interface directly.